# Powershell convert to json removes special characters

Tags: json, powershell

I have problem with save string to json file.

```
$newY = "12313tytk1.xp1`F4i12313211ddsada;"
```

First I read json file

```
$a = Get-Content 'settings.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then updating field

```
$a.X.y = $newY
```

And saving file

```
$a | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 | set-content 'settings.json'
```

There are some problems:

1. After save `Y` in file is wrong:

   "12313tytk1.xp1F4i12313211ddsada;" 
   The special characters are missing: `.
2. File is wrongly formatted. To much spaces
3. "<" and ">" are changed to: `\u003c` and `\u003e`

How to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bactick  `` ` `` is an escape character in Powershell. Single quoted strings `'` are string literals, so the contents are not evaluated, escaped or the like. Doulbe quoted strings `"` are evaluated, so the backtick is interpreted as an escape character. See [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) for more information.

Consider,

```
PS C:\> $newY = "12313tytk1.xp1`F4i12313211ddsada;"
PS C:\> $newY # Misses the backtick
12313tytk1.xp1F4i12313211ddsada;
PS C:\>  $newY2 = '12313tytk1.xp1`F4i12313211ddsada;'
PS C:\>  $newY2 # Contains the backtick
12313tytk1.xp1`F4i12313211ddsada;
```